# excel add-in .xla reference from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an addin and added as a reference on another workbook after installing; however when I open the workbook where the add-in is referenced, the add-in workbook open too; how can I avoid to ahve the add-in workbook opened? I do have a routine called from the add-in workbook_open event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to first save the add-in as xlam and also to refer it from code and not from the excel add-ins menu item